# Why wasn't Malekith able to see through Frigga's illusion?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

This is arguably a plot hole but when Malekith and Kurse barged into Frigga's room looking for the Aether, after a brief skirmish, he approaches Jane and proceeds to extract the Aether from her body

> but as he touches her, it is revealed that she was an illusion all along created by Frigga.

With Malekith's strong connection to the Aether, being able to sense its power when Thor smuggled Jane to the dark world, he was able to sense the Aether as they closed in on his location. With his Aether-sensing abilities, how was he not able to sense that Jane in front of him was a decoy illusion?

Answer (score 4):

**There are several possibilities which present themselves:**

- The Aether may not always broadcast its location or the broadcast is intermittent.
- Strong broadcasting may damage the host organism, and since the Aether is trying to get to a host willing to use it, it may not want to damage Jane Foster until it can be found. Since Malekith had been able to track it successfully, it need do nothing but wait.
- Frigga was an Asgardian very familiar with magic. It may be she simply was skilled enough to mask the presence of the Aether for a short time.

**Most likely:**

- Given the power of the Aether, it is highly likely that Malekith's connection to the Aether was overwhelmed given his proximity to it. His senses may be strong enough to detect it at distance but not precise enough to determine its specific location once in the presence of it. The power simply blinded him once he was too close.

Comment: +1 for the Most Likely explanation. It's one thing to know it's on Asgard, and then in the palace once you get there, but "this room" vs. "the room next door" probably gets a little fuzzy.